# popup div hide() when click anywhere else - jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I know there are quite a few posts about this question and I have tried few codes and thought it worked perfectly with mine but then I found out it only worked (hides) when I click on the same `<div>` that makes it pop and also when I click anywhere not within my `#main` `<div>`.  So if I click anywhere within my `#main` `<div>`, my pop-up will just stay there.  I have been looking at it for awhile and couldn't see why.

Can someone please give me an eye?

Edit:
These are the codes I have.

my html where I have the select option and the colorSelectBox

```
<div class="color-side-a">
    <p class="sideABCD-header">Side A</p>
    <div class="dimension-width">
        <p class="dimension-WHC">Colors</p>
        <select name="number-of-colors" class="number-of-colors color-a">
            <option value="" group="1">Select A Number</option>
            <option value="1" group="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" group="1">2</option>
            <option value="3" group="1">3</option>
        </select>
        <div class="number-of-color-field">
            <div name="color1" class="sideA color1" data-semi="false"  data-coated="false"></div>
            <div name="color2" class="sideA color2" data-semi="false"  data-coated="false"></div>
            <div name="color3" class="sideA color3" data-semi="false"  data-coated="false"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end color side A -->


<div class="colorSelectBox">
    <div>14 Guage Semi-Transparent</div>
    <div>
        <div class="azRed" value="#DD2A13" name="Aztec Red"></div>
        <div class="azYellow" value="#E5BC0A" name="Aztec Yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div>18 oz Industrial Stength Viyl Coated</div>
    <div>
        <div class="yellow" value="yellow" name="yellow"></div>
        <div class="blue" value="blue" name="blue"></div>
        <div class="black" value="black" name="black"></div>
        <div class="brown" value="brown" name="brown"></div>
        <div class="grey" value="grey" name="grey"></div>
        <div class="green" value="green" name="green"></div>
        <div class="white" value="white" name="white"></div>
        <div class="orange" value="orange" name="orange"></div>
    </div>
```

this is what's in js

```
var colorHolder = null; //used to store the location where color is picked

/* Function checks which side's div is clicked and pop put the colorSelectBox with the position of the div popping out */
function colorFieldPicker(onClickSide,side){
    onClickSide.on('click', function(event){
        //store the class of the colorHolder to a global variable
        colorHolder = $(this).attr('class');
        var yVal = (event.clientY) + "px";
        var xVal = (event.clientX) + "px";
        $('.colorSelectBox').css({"left": xVal, "top": yVal}).toggle();
        //empty the field where it says 'Click to choose colors'
        $(this).closest('div').find('.gradient').children().empty();
        //var visible = $('.colorSelectBox').hasClass('visible');
        //if(visible){
        //    $('.colorSelectBox').hide();
        //    $('.colorSelectBox').removeClass('visible');
        //}else{
        //    $('.colorSelectBox').show();
        //    $('.colorSelectBox').addClass('visible');
        //}
        colorPickerOnClick(side);

    });
}
/* Function which then determine what color is clicked and return the color to the div selected as the div's background color */
function colorPickerOnClick(side){
    //semi colors on click
    $('div.azRed')
        .add('div.azYellow')
        .on('click', function(){
        var colorAttr = $(this).attr('value');
        var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        var splitClass = colorHolder.split(" ");
        side.closest('div').find('.'+splitClass[0] + '.'+splitClass[1])
            .css({"background": colorAttr, "border": "none"})
            .attr({"value": colorAttr, "data-semi": true, "data-coated": false, "name": nameAttr});
        $('.colorSelectBox').css({"display": "none"});
    });

    //coated color on click
    $('div.white').on('click', function(){
        var colorAttr = $(this).attr('value');
        var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        var splitClass = colorHolder.split(" ");
        side.closest('div').find('.'+splitClass[0] + '.'+splitClass[1])
            .css({"background": colorAttr, "border": "1px solid lightgrey"})
            .attr({"value": colorAttr, "data-semi": false, "data-coated": true, "name": nameAttr});
        $('.colorSelectBox').css({"display": "none"});
    });
}
```

The above is the original code and I have searched online and found this, which is also what Diego provided,

```
/*Makes the colorSelect hide when mouse clicked other places*/
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".colorSelectBox");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

The code above works well but what I really want is when I click on the certain `div` the box pop up and the box will be gone when I click on the same `div` again or anywhere outside of the box. The code above only works perfectly when I click anywhere outside the box but if I click on the `div` that makes it pop up the box would only change position to my mouse position.  I tried adding / removing class as it is now commented out in my code and can be seen above, it works but still have problem because when I click anywhere outside the box, the class for the box will not remove and so I added that removing class into the code above that if anywhere outside of the box is clicked the class will be removed.  But that doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't inspect the page because i'm on my tablet but i'm pretty sure this 'div' is a `<select>` with some `<options>` inside. Do you really need it to be a custom div ?

Comment: I realized in the "view source" of the page, each js function is marked with description "function to". You might wanna check through all such instances to find the code which actually does what you are looking for.

Comment: @Lauromine the `select a number` is a `<select>` and depending on the value select the # of `<div>` will pop out

Answer (score 0):

I got kind of lucky and I think I found your jQuery code for hiding the colorbox div.

```
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.colorSelectBox').length > 0 || $(e.target).closest('div').length > 0) return;
        $('.colorSelectBox').hide();
    });
```

The reason it won't hide it, is because of the second condition:

```
$(e.target).closest('div').length > 0
```

It basically says, if the element clicked is a child of a div or a div then don't hide it. Since you have divs everywhere it will always return that function and never hide. I don't know what you were trying here.

Comment: what is wanted is after the div popped out, either select one of the colors in the div that popped out then the div would hide or clicking anywhere else other than the popped div would also hide it.

Comment: You don't need the second condition then. Just removing it should work. The first condition is ok, if you click anywhere on the `.colorSelectBox` it won't hide the `div`, everything else will.  You have another function to hide the `.colorSelectBox` when any of the options is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `$(document).click` function at line:690  with this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $(".colorSelectBox");

  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
  {
      container.hide();
  }
});
```

Check this question: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I actually tried this too which has the same reaction.

Comment: yes that is exactly how it works, did you tried this solution?

Comment: yup that's what I meant, this is actually the first coding I found and tried but also wouldn't hide when in any other elements are clicked. So searched for quite a few other ways and still couldn't figure out that's why I posted this thread :(

Comment: try it, i'm 100% sure this works but you have to replace the code at line 717 the whole $(document).click function

Comment: the function you have to delete is on line 717, this:
 $(document).click(function (e) {
         if ($(e.target).closest('.colorSelectBox').length > 0 || $(e.target).closest('div').length > 0) return;
         $('.colorSelectBox').hide();
     });

Comment: yup I get what you mean.  Let me try again. because as you can see right above the function asked me to delete, there's another function above which is commented out.  It was originally the exactly as the one you posted but then didn't work so played around with it then commented out.  But let me try again.

Comment: ah ok I remember why that was commented out and played around with.  It's because when clicking on the same div which makes the pop up div come out, clicking on the same div wouldn't toggle it.  That's why I was finding other ways

Comment: what do you mean? I really cannot find why this solution doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88428/discussion-between-diego-lopez-and-dora).